# Create fake data (API) for building and developing Vue app

Tags: api, vuejs2

I have to build a Vue JS app. I need some data with some fixed fields (title, description, price, category), so I am able to build my functionalities and components. What is convenient way to build this API for testing purposes. So it should be fake data but mapped to specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

make an api folder then fill it will example text files that are json objec.t you can then import these into your app and modify the files to change the data?

api/title.json

```
{
"title": "Something"
"description" : "Other"
}
```

`import data from "./api/title.son"`

Then data should be the object contained in the file.

Comment: no I need a lot of data to test my functionalities. I think I am going to use JSON Server and Faker